# How to reset the cache in SharePoint Content Database?

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to clear the cache in the SharePoint Content database so it will read data from the local files in my server. I am trying to do this because I am performing some testing and this is part of our testing requirements. Is there anyway to do it?
As I searched, there are ways to reset the Configuration Database cache but I find nothing about clearing the Content cache so it will read data from the server's local files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about [Flush the BLOB cache in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/flush-the-blob-cache). A BLOB cache is a disk-based cache that stores binary large objects (BLOBs) such as frequently used image, audio, and video files, and other files that are used to display web pages. Hope this may help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't reset the content database.